# Eigenvalues of a $3\times3$ orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

Can anyone give me an example of 3x3 orthogonal matrix with complex eigenvalue.

Comment: $i\cdot\mathcal I_3$ ?

Comment: The English terms are eigenvalue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) and characteristic polynomial (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial).

Comment: thank you, i will correct my post :)

Comment: It's actually rather German :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example. Let
$$
U=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\0&-1&0 \end{matrix}\right).
$$
Then, $U$ is orthogonal and its characteristic polynomial is 
$$
p(\lambda)=\det\,\left(\begin{matrix}1-\lambda&0&0\\ 0&-\lambda&1\\0&-1&-\lambda \end{matrix}\right)
=-(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2+1).
$$